Docker can't create symlink because a file it creates already exists
Plattform: Nvidia Jetson Nano with Edge TPU installed
Docker version: Docker version 20.10.21, build 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~18.04.3
Ubuntu version:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
(this version is from the official Nvidia Image)
When executing the command:
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:/mnt/sd/SHMT$ sudo sh scripts/docker_setup_partition.sh 
[sudo] password for nvidia: 
[gpgtpu_partition] - building docker image from dockerfile...
[+] Building 2.5s (23/23) FINISHED                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.4.4           2.1s
 => [auth] nvidia/l4t-base:pull token for nvcr.io                          0.0s
 => [opencv_base 1/4] FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.4.4@sha256:e9d0631  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 81B                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [opencv_base 2/4] COPY ./opencv_install_deps.sh opencv_install  0.0s
 => CACHED [opencv_base 3/4] RUN ./opencv_install_deps.sh                  0.0s
 => CACHED [opencv_base 4/4] RUN echo $(ls -lh /usr/include/$(uname -i)-l  0.0s
 => CACHED [build1 1/4] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$CONTAINER_TIMEZO  0.0s
 => CACHED [build1 2/4] RUN  sh -c "echo '/usr/local/cuda/lib64' >> /etc/  0.0s
 => CACHED [build1 3/4] RUN  ldconfig                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [build1 4/4] RUN  apt-get install -y build-essential cmake git  0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 1/7] COPY update_sources.sh /                           0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 2/7] RUN /update_sources.sh                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 3/7] RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf                  0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 4/7] RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64                  0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 5/7] RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get instal  0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 6/7] RUN apt-get install -y libeigen3-dev &&     sudo   0.0s
 => CACHED [build2 7/7] RUN apt-get install -y python-scipy                0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/2] RUN echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/l  0.0s
 => CACHED [final 2/2] WORKDIR /home                                       0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:9c2344e9f541d38be18d04500859cdae3703ba3380271  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/gpgtpu_partition_image                  0.0s
gpgtpu_partition_container
gpgtpu_partition_container
[gpgtpu_partition] - build docker container...
42388e49673538748e6f8931cbbb0404455be5e92d7e6f72e319c3c2b5d3a4bd
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #1: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: time="2024-12-03T05:12:28-05:00" level=info msg="Symlinking /mnt/sd/docker-data/overlay2/ecdbbf8f1a0d9147b218c4edbdb70b3d82fe18e175fcd02ed6c9ba34933b475b/merged/etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json to /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/nvidia_icd.json"
time="2024-12-03T05:12:28-05:00" level=error msg="failed to create link [/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/nvidia_icd.json /etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json]: failed to create symlink: failed to remove existing file: remove /mnt/sd/docker-data/overlay2/ecdbbf8f1a0d9147b218c4edbdb70b3d82fe18e175fcd02ed6c9ba34933b475b/merged/etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json: device or resource busy": unknown.
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:/mnt/sd/SHMT$ 

The folder that this symlink is supposed to be created in is recreated every time the script runs and the original file isn't being held by anything:
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:/mnt/sd/SHMT$ lsof | grep /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/nvidia_icd.json
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:/mnt/sd/SHMT$ lsof | grep /etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:/mnt/sd/SHMT$ lsof | grep /mnt/sd/docker-data/overlay2/ecdbbf8f1a0d9147b218c4edbdb70b3d82fe18e175fcd02ed6c9ba34933b475b/merged/etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:/mnt/sd/SHMT$ 

docker run script
#!/bin/sh

GITTOP="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2\>&1)"

# source configure file

. "${GITTOP}/configure.cfg"
PROJ=${GPGTPU_PARTITION}

# paths setup

DOCKERFILE_PATH="${GITTOP}/docker/partition_scheme"
IMAGE_NAME=${PROJ}\_image
CONTAINER_NAME=${PROJ}\_container
DATASET_DIR="${DATASET_HOST_ROOT}"
SRC_DIR="${GITTOP}"
DATASET_TARGET_DIR="${DATASET_MOUNT}" # the dataset mount point within container
SRC_TARGET_DIR="${SRC_MOUNT}" # the src code mount point within container

# build dockerfile to generate docker image

echo "\[${PROJ}\] - building docker image from dockerfile..."
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 nvidia-docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME} ${DOCKERFILE_PATH}

nvidia-docker stop ${CONTAINER_NAME}
nvidia-docker rm ${CONTAINER_NAME}

# generate container from image

# mount dataset dir (ImageNet)/src  from host fs to container fs

# get the container running

echo "\[${PROJ}\] - build docker container..."

# Use 'priviledged' flag to enable edgetpu access

nvidia-docker run -d \
\-it \
\--privileged \
\-e IS_GPGTPU_CONTAINER='true' \
\--name ${CONTAINER_NAME} \
\--runtime=nvidia \
\-e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all \
\--gpus all \
\--mount type=bind,source=/etc/passwd,target=/etc/passwd,readonly \
\--mount type=bind,source=/etc/group,target=/etc/group,readonly \
\-u $(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER) \
\--mount type=bind,source=${SRC_DIR},target=${SRC_TARGET_DIR} \
\--mount type=bind,source=${GPTPU_LIB_BASE},target=${GPTPU_LIB_MOUNT} \
\--mount type=bind,source=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu,target=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu,readonly \
${IMAGE_NAME} \
bash

Things I already tried that didnt work:
reinstalling docker
using a different storage driver (vfs instead of overlay2)
removing the file while the script is running using another script
mounting a copy of the file to make sure it isn't in use
The sricpt was supposed to make a docker container but instead it fails everytime
this code is from this git repo
